# UITabBarController crashing issue

Tags: iphone

i have used UITabBarController Application. i have add 10 navigation controller inside tabbar.only five item show on the tabbar. bt when we click no 5 itemtabbar second time then application crashed. Error(Interrupted).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this error (message sent to deallocated instance ) means that you are releasing something early and again you want to access . check where you release something and again using it .

Comment: i suggest do proper memory management while do coding . ok i think you are new to iphone development so i give you a hit and trial method that you comment all the release and nil in your project and then check your project again and again whenever to get where you release you uncomment all object.if u like my answer upvote it

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar has nothing to do with it. You are sending your `UITableView` too many release calls. Make sure that the `FavoriteTableViewController` has proper memory management. My guess is that you are sending it an autorelease when you create it and later on when you leave the screen you send it another release or viceversa.